# 40 year old dev lost at sea and looking for advice

Tags: software-industry, job-search, job-offer

I´m a 40 year old, single and without children, developer. I have a CS degree and I´ve been working as a developer for almost 20 years.

I live and work in Argentina. Argentina has, depending on the information source, a 20-30% yearly inflation rate.

Most dev jobs here are in professional services companies (software factories, staffing), and the few product companies that exist are starting to follow the model of said services companies: a strong hierarchical model where dev is seen as "any can do" work and teams are composed mostly of junior programmers. Someone with 5 years of experience is seen as an expert there.

From 2013 to date all jobs I could get were in professional services companies, be it in software factories or as an external employee with a client. Payment and stability have been poor, treatment has been worse.

Now I face a dilemma, I have 2 job opportunities.

One is as a dev where the pay is good. I've met the owner, who was (or still is) a director in a professional services at a CoWorking. I will work there and he will hire me through another company, because his company is still not registered after a year of operations, in fact the company does not even have a web site. The only thing he has under his belt is that he has grown 2 professional services companies before, and I can confirm that. But it could also be that he has just got a couple of contracts through contacts and is working with them as extra. He told me that his business model will be based on skills and experience instead of being cheap, but his few company employees on Linkedin are in their early/middle twenties. He also showed me the money first and told me about the position later.

The other opportunity is as a business analyst in a mid sized professional services company specialized in the energy industry. The pay is 25% less but it could probably give me some leverage to grow as a PM or Delivery Manager or at least an escape from all the mistreatment I get as an old external dev.

Given a choice I wouldn´t program anymore. The last 5 years have been programmer´s hell, and all the stress and mistreatment literally cost me an eye, my left eye. But inflation is high here, and money is really needed.

Does the first option sound too much of a risk?

Comment: `Does the first option sound too much of a risk` You and you alone can answer that. But ask yourself this - if it wasn't too much risk would you be asking us here?

Answer (score -2):

Too much of a risk depends on what your personal tolerance is to risk and how much you depend on having a stable income, everyone’s circumstances are different.

If money is really needed as you’ve suggested maybe the first option isn’t suitable, or at least until the company gets of the ground. Depending on your personal circumstances if the opportunity outweighs the risk only you can decide and any answer would be opinion based.

As you’ve stated, you would move away from programming if you could so does this not help make your mind up? You have a choice developer or BA.

Comment: Because every time we seem to have the same answer or comment on the same post, my account gets deleted. I don’t want to be deleted again, so I’d rather try and avoid this.

Comment: Same building, different office. I’ve been discussing the question I raised on meta and we decided it best not to post the answers and one is better off deleting. TWYXZ actually recommended I check out workplace after being a member of stack overflow for years, however since then I’ve ended up having both accounts banned.

Comment: Not many questions are posted on workplace so it’s quite common we both end up answering the same thing without knowing, I don’t know how we can avoid this in future without someone picking up on it. But we’re two separate people with different opinions, which isn’t against any of the rules

Comment: Yeah but there’s nothing to pick up. I was contributing towards the community in general and not just twyxz posts, if they’d looked into my account theyd see it. I’ve also tried to inform support of this. I’ve been a member of stack exchange for quite a few years longer than twyxz and in turn have actually lost a lot of stuff, which doesn’t make sense in itself. If my account was for the purposes of sock puppetting, I don’t understand how the account would be older than the person accused of orchestrating it.